# Very different results from same Keras model, built with Sequential or functional style

Tags: python, keras, model

I am trying to implement a Keras regression model that learns to set some parameters, e.g there are some parameters in input and a set of unrelated outputs, coherent with the inputs (e.g. similar inputs give similar outputs in the training set, and there is partial linearity between some inputs and some outputs).
Inputs and outputs are normalized, since the parameters have different units.

The training phase results in a mse of ~ 0.48 and the predictions are rather sensible.

This is the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(78, activation='relu', input_shape = 3))
model.add(Dense(54, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(54, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5))
```

summary:

```
X:  (2011, 3) y:  (2011, 5)
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 78)                312       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 54)                4266      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 54)                2970      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 275       
=================================================================
Total params: 7,823
Trainable params: 7,823
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Then I make exactly the same model functional-style

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=3) #(X.shape[1],)
out = keras.layers.Dense(78, activation='relu')(inputs)
out = keras.layers.Dense(54, activation='relu')(out)
out = keras.layers.Dense(54, activation='relu')(out)
out = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu')(out)


X:  (2011, 3) y:  (2011, 5)
Model: "func_model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 3)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 78)                312       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 54)                4266      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 54)                2970      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 275       
=================================================================
Total params: 7,823
Trainable params: 7,823
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The summary is exactly the same, except that the functional has the input layer added.. but the docs say:

```
When a popular kwarg input_shape is passed, then keras will create an input layer 
to insert before the current layer. This can be treated equivalent to explicitly
defining an InputLayer.
```

https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/

which is what I do in the first model. So the two models should be the same. But they are not: mse during training is noticeably higher, ~ 0.7, and contrary to the other model the predictions are "flattened": the output set is minimally responsive to the input parameters.

Any consideration?

Comment: do you have a link to full code and data? I suspect the difference is in your data handle code

Comment: https://gist.github.com/danielemezzetti/949f207a65661b9bb36f01dcd6b07a0d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in your output layer activation. In functional you use relu:

```
out = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu')(out)
```

in sequential, you use linear (the default activation)

```
model.add(Dense(5))
```

the correct output activation depends on the data you are modeling, but the difference is what gives you the confusing results.

edit: after looking at your question, it looks like your functional model should change the last line to

```
out = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='linear')(out)
```

or simply

```
out = keras.layers.Dense(5)(out)
```

Comment: Thank you.. this overlooked activation is indeed the culprit